# How to add string into Hash with each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, each

```
x = "one two"
y = x.split

hash = {}

y.each do |key, value|
  hash[key] = value
end
print hash
```

The result of this is: one=> nil, two => nil

I want to make "one" - key, and "two" - value, but how to do this?

It may look like this:  "one" => "two"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit faster way of doing it:

```
x="one two"
Hash[[x.split]]
```

If you're looking for a more general solution where x could have more elements, consider something like this:

```
hash = {}
x="one two three four"
x.split.each_slice(2) do |key, value| # each_slice(n) pulls the next n elements from an array
  hash[key] = value
end

hash
```

Or, if you're really feeling fancy, try using inject:

```
x="one two three four"
x.split.each_slice(2).inject({}) do |memo, (key, value)|
  memo[key] = value
  memo
end
```

Comment: Actually @Zhong Zheng's answer is more elegant. My solution's good if for some reason you're set on using each (or each_slice) methods and is perhaps useful for educational purposes, but in the real world `Hash[*y]` is cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

`y` is an array, therefore in the block `key` is the item itself ('one', 'two'), and value is always nil.

You can convert an array to hash using splat operator `*`

`Hash[*y]`